# Skew image with Raphael?

Tags: svg, raphael

I was wondering whether it's possible to 'skew' only one side of the image, with Raphael JS?
As can be seen in the images below. (the right rectangle and the 'marshall' text)

Thanks in advance!

Laurens

[image]

[image]

Comment: SVG does not support non-affine transforms.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: Whilst you can't skew it in svg, you could skew the whole svg with css I think, then you would have to have different svg papers depending on complexity and desired browser support it may be possible ?

Comment: Hi, actually I found a workaround for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/xjHUk/86/

Comment: you have to use Paper.path(pathstring)